# Как добавлять объекты в префаб через иерархию?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Сделал префаб персонажа в моём проекте, но не получается добавить объекты в нём через иерархию. Как собственно решить эту проблему?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1 вариант - попробуй зажат лкм объект из иерархии и перетащить в окно
2 вариант - на первой фотке есть значки - попробуй нажать на них и выбрать объекты из предложенных
Если это не получится - значит у тебя не совпадают виды объектов и то, что ты хочешь перетащить. Например, ты пытаешься затащить Game object в Transform.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы уже сделали префаб то добавить объекты из обычной сцены прямо в префаб невозможно. Вам надо будет создать экземпляр префаба на сцене с помощью `Instantiate` и добавить этот объект уже к нему.

Answer (score 0):

Сделай то что нужно закинуть префабами, или ищи их в коде с помощью GameObject.Find("имя");

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]